# How can I cover my pressure transmitter sensors with a material that will protect it from being dirty and at the same time not interfere with signal

Tags: sensor, signal, electrically-conductive

I am an engineer in oil field and am using a wireless system for data acquisition.
The logger is connected to an antenna which receives the signal from the pressure transmitter sensors. I am working on a large field using one system thus I depend on the sensors to transmit signals to each other to reach the antenna. The sensors are placed in various places and there are operations that takes place on top of the sensor which might damage the sensor if anything falls on it either chemical or hard object.
When I cover the sensor to protect it, the signal is lost more frequently thus interrupting the operation. I am looking for a material that I can use to cover the sensor with yet doesn't interfere or affect the signal ot is sending.

Answer (score 6):

This is a tiny bit simplifying, but any *nonconductive* material you're likely to meet is going to not absorb RF energy. So, ABS, PET, Teflon, dry wood, acrylic, polyurethane foam, fiberglass/polymer materials … work well. Glass usually does, too, unless it's been coated with a conductive film.

Metal, carbon fibers, wet substances, material containing iron filings, steel-reinforced concrete, graphite… absorb or reflect radio waves to varying degrees and should be avoided.

The effect that all materials have on waves is the same that you can observe when light (which is also just electromagnetic waves) travels through materials with different refractive indices: It bends! You know the effect if you ever noticed your spoon seems to have a bend when looked at through tea.

There's one thing to keep in mind though: if you have a different material than air so close to the antenna that it affects the near field of the antenna, that might change the antennas properties and thus its workings and efficiency. So, keep your cover a wavelength away from the antenna, and you should be mostly fine! Remember that a wavelength in air is \$\frac{c_0}{f} = \frac{3\cdot 10^8\,\text{m}}{f/\text{Hz}}\$.

Comment: To slightly desimplify the tiny bit simplifying, anything with strong magnetic properties will interfere with RF energy too, so ferrites are out. Not that you would want to use a piece of very brittle ferrite to provide mechanical protection.